# Android LinearLayout: Layout inside a Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am confused by Android layout design. I want to achieve the layout in the following image:[image]

But the code below is producing something like this image:
[image]

**My code**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_shadow"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/detailsLay">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/repeat"
            android:id="@+id/repeatCheckBox"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:paddingTop="15sp"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:paddingLeft="1sp"
            android:paddingBottom="15sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20sp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/sat"
            android:id="@+id/satTextView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/arrowDown"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/everyday"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use a `relativeLayout` instead

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` else use Different layout for `LinearLayour2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a Sample Xml learn from this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CheckBox" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Use attributes like weight and user orientation of linearlayout.